# Custom logout with method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm writing a web project with Spring Boot and Spring Security.

I want to logout in a method instead of URL `/logout`. For example: a controller method get a URL, then this method do something and logout.

My Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
```

But I don't know how to logout with a method. What should I do in `SecurityConfig.class`? What should I do in the method to logout without a URL?

Comment: Why? As you are really bypassing a lot of logout functionality which you then need to replicate yourself... (Spring Security does more then just invalidate the session at hand).

Comment: I just want to logout in a method not a url . i just want to know which object should i call ，and which method i should call to logout when i find the user do something wrong. @dur

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method inside your Controller and using the method logout of the SecurityContextLogoutHandler class, to logout the current user.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/custom-logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String customLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Get the Spring Authentication object of the current request.
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    // In case you are not filtering the users of this request url.
    if (authentication != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authentication); // <= This is the call you are looking for.
    }
    return "redirect:/login-page";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logoutUrl")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html?logout=true")
    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler)
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

This logout the user ie clears the SecurityContext, and redirects to page index.html?logout=true after successfully logging out.
You can also define a LogoutSuccessHandler which implements LogoutHandler, and implement onLogoutSuccess() for adding any post logout logic for your use case.
Spring gives few implementations of LogoutHandler like SecurityContextLogoutHandler, SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler etc. Check for more in spring security docs.
invalidateHttpSession(true)  invalidates your httpsession.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I's not to logout with another url ,I just want to a method to logout Server。 for example   I want to logout in main function sometime。 how should i do? in some function , I found user do something i dont want to do(for example wrong param),I need logout. how should I do?  @Praneeth Ramesh

Comment: Do you mean any inside any method, you just want to logout the user. In SpringSecurity Logout just means clearing the Securitycontext. Just Call SecurityContextHolder.clearContext(); would do it. Also you may want to invalidate HttpSession.invalidate(); You may also have to consider clearing cookies and stuffs depending on your use case. Or HttpServletRequest.logout() this would also be a cleaner way to do the same.

Comment: thank you very much, with your guidance ，I finished it! @Praneeth Ramesh